# Java Flight Recording for JDK 8

Tags: java, jfr, java-mission-control

I just read about Java Flight Recording and figured out that it's a commercial feature. Since it's enabled by `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder`. so the question is if it's possible for me to use it in our production environment for profiling. I use

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Or it is illegal to do so?

Comment: If you are using JDK 8u60, the command line flag -XX:+FlightRecorder is not needed, only the-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software license terms

Comment: Duplicate of [*Does openjdk 1.8.0_242 supports Java Flight Recorder?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61333887/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Java Flight Recorder requires a commercial license for use in
>   production

https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm#JFRUH170

so yes, it's likely illegal.

Comment: **Update:** No longer requires a fee. Oracle open-sourced both [*Flight Recorder*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328) and [*Mission Recorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Mission_Control) as sub-projects housed on the [*OpenJDK*](https://openjdk.java.net) project. Builds available from vendors such as Azul Systems, Oracle, and others.