# Does openjdk 1.8.0_242 supports Java Flight Recorder?

Tags: java

I want to run a java application with JFR enabled. When I start my application as below 
java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:StartFlightRecording

I get following error **Unrecognized VM option -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures*

Does OPENJDK 1.8.0_242 supports Java Flight Recorder?
build is 1.8.0_242-b07

Comment: It sounds like "no, but a future point release of OpenJDK 8 will": https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/02/jfr-coming-to-openjdk-8/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150612/jdk-flight-recorder-backport-in-redhat-openjdk-8/60295801#comment109275237_60295801

Comment: JFR was originally a proprietary feature of the Oracle JDK, so -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures applies only to Oracle JDK.

Oracle JDK 11 emits a warning when using the -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures option, whereas OpenJDK doesn’t recognize this option and reports an error.
(ref https://dzone.com/articles/using-java-flight-recorder-with-openjdk-11-1)

Answer (score 3):

No it does not.
As per the [release notes for openjdk8u262](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2020-July/012143.html), it is supported in OpenJDK 8 update 262.

> New features - [JDK-8223147](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223147): JFR Backport

Answer (score 1):

Oracle open-sourced both [*Flight Recorder*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328) and [*Mission Recorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Mission_Control) as sub-projects housed on the [*OpenJDK*](https://openjdk.java.net) project. Builds available from vendors such as Azul Systems, Oracle, and others. Some may be free-of-cost, some may not; read the terms.

## *Zulu Community* edition, by Azul Systems

[Azul Systems, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems) is currently shipping their [*Zulu Community*](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-community/) product built on *OpenJDK*. [Java Flight Recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Flight_Recorder) and [Mission Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Mission_Control) are both included for Java 8 according to [their feature matrix](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-community/free-jdk-comparison-matrix/).

[Also included](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/zuluentfaq/) in their commercial product, [Zulu Enterprise](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/).

Caveat: I have not used Flight Recorder with either Zulu. Just found it from some web searching.

---

By the way, [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) improvements are also being [back-ported to Java 8](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/04/tls-alpn-java8/).